# Blender 2.8 color material cause model to distort

Tags: python, materials, interface

Help me resolve the problem of **model distortion** especially when color material is applied in Blender 2.8 and above.[image]

Why is no one trying to help me. Am stocked and need assistant please.

Comment: Recommend add a minimal example file to the question preferably using https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and try to describe your issue in detail in order to get help, https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=9X3OmlVS" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/9X3OmlVS/)